# ASCII decoding in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can anyone decode ascii value in iOS?

I can decode single character value but more than one character i cant decode

Thanks in advance.

---

This is my string value

> <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><prestashop></prestashop>

the ascii encoded value is

> 62651221111103412010311611710711311263365148503634103112101113102107112105633687‌​867247583634656462114116103117118991171061131146462491141161031171189911710611311‌​464

Comment: What do you mean by "decrypt"? ASCII isn't ciphertext, it's a character encoding (i.e. plain text).

Comment: __Show us some code__ :) How are you 'decrypting' a single character? What does the 'more than one character' ascii look like? Where does it come from?

Comment: Decode to what? Code would be useful, if you don't know standard terminology.

Comment: FYI: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: this is my string value  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><prestashop></prestashop>   the ascii encoded value is  62651221111103412010311611710711311263365148503634103112101113102107112105633687867247583634656462114116103117118991171061131146462491141161031171189911710611311464    now i need the actual string value

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Why are you talking about ascii at all - surely you're getting an `NSString` already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ascii is just a string encoding

you only need to have this:

```
NSData *ascii = ... //asci data
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ascii encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

or

```
char *cStringInAscii = "lalalalasada";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:cStringInAscii encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```